# how to add Save button to each row of the Oracle APEX Report

Tags: oracle-apex

I have created an APEX report with Edit Link and Drop Down box. Edit Link is used to edit all the fields of the report. But I would like to add a 'save' button next to Edit link so that users can change values in Drop Down and save the record instead of going to next page using Edit link. Please provide an option to achive this

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an [Updateable report (tabular form)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14373_01/appdev.32/e11838/app_comp.htm#BCEECEFA).